# Convergance of series

Tags: calculus

**Question:**

$\sum _{n=1}^\infty a_n$ doesn't converge

1. Does  $\sum _{n=1}^\infty {a_n \over {1+n^2a_n}}$ converge?
2. Does $\sum _{n=1}^\infty {a_n \over {1+a_n^2}}$ converge?

**What I did**:

1. $\frac {a_n}{1+n^2a_n}< \frac {a_n}{n^2a_n}=\frac 1{n^2}$ And by the comparison test this series converges.
2. $\frac {a_n}{1+a_n^2}< \frac {a_n}{a_n^2}=\frac 1{a_n}$ Now since 
   $\sum _{n=1}^\infty a_n$ doesn't converge then $\lim_{n \to \infty } a_n \ne  0 \Rightarrow \frac 1{a_n}<\infty \Rightarrow \frac {a_n}{1+a_n^2}$ converges.

I would like to verify that these solution are correct, and if they're not please hint me where I'm mistaking. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your statement
$\sum _{n=1}^\infty a_n$ doesn't converge then $\lim_{n \to \infty } a_n \ne  0$ is not correct. The converse is true that is, if $a_n$ does not converge to $0$ then $\sum _{n=1}^\infty a_n$ doesn't converge.

Comment: Okay, You are indeed correct (I keep on making that same mistake with that one...) Any hint on a different way to crack this one? Or should I just divide $a_n$'s limits to cases?

Answer (score 2):

You did the first part just fine, assuming that the $a_n$ are positive. If they need not be positive, the problem becomes noticeably harder.

For the second part, what if $a_n=1$ for each $n$?

**Added:** Indeed, as Harald Hanche-Olsen points out in the comments below, the first part becomes impossible if the $a_n$ are allowed to be negative. Let

$$a_n=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\\\\
\frac1{n^4}-\frac1{n^2},&\text{if }n\text{is even}\;.
\end{cases}$$

The terms with odd indices ensure that $\sum_{n\ge 1}a_n$ diverges. On the other hand, when $n$ is even we have

$$\frac{a_n}{1+n^2a_n}=\frac{\frac1{n^4}-\frac1{n^2}}{1+\frac1{n^2}-1}=\frac1{n^2}-1\to -1\quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty\;,$$

so the new series diverges as well.

Comment: If the $a_n$ aren't positive, I see the potential for big trouble in the first part. What if $a_n\approx -1/n^2$ infinitely often? (If you have equality, you can't even write up the sequence, of course.)

Comment: @Harald: Yes, that’s why I just revised my answer! I’ve been thinking about it, and while I think that the result may still be true — getting a lot of bad denominators may force $\sum a_n$ to converge — it’s definitely not straightforward.

Comment: Consider this: $a_n=1$ for $n$ odd, $a_n=n^{-4}-n^{-2}$ for $n$ even.

Comment: @Harald: Thanks for taking the time to think about it!

Comment: Thanks guys for all the thought!

Comment: @user1685224: You’re welcome!